# Biblatex: different appearance of footnote reference according to \defbibheading

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing my PhD Thesis using XeLaTex. I have a rather simple question, I think.

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = Example.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
    \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
    \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,german}
        \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}
        \setkeys{latin}{variant=modern}
        \setkeys{german}{babelshorthands=true}

%Bibliografia
\usepackage[%
    style=philosophy-modern,% 
    backend=biber,%
    classical=true,%
    scauthors = bibcite,%
          dashed = true,%
          volnumformat = parens,%
          volumeformat = Roman,%
%   firstinits=true,%
    volnumformat=strings,%
    volumeformat=romansc,%
    sorting=nyt,%
    relatedformat=brackets,%
    indexing]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{
editor = {{ed.}},
editors = {{edd.}},
%
}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book, article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{{} -- {}}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{{} -- {}}


\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\defbibheading{abbreviazioni}{\subsection{#1}}
\defbibheading{edizioni}{\subsection{#1}}
\defbibheading{studi}{\subsection{#1}}

\begin{document}

Hi\footnote{\cite{Gabras.1973}.}

Hallo\footnote{\cite{Cotsonis.2005}}

\section{\bibname}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=edizioni,keyword=edizioni,title={Primary Sources}]
\printbibliography[heading=studi,keyword=studi,title={Secondary Sources}]

\end{document}
```

Contents of bibliografia.bib:

```
@book{Gabras.1973,
keywords = {edizioni},
 author = {{Michael Gabras}},
 editor = {Fatouros, Geōrgios},
 year = {1973},
 title = {Die Briefe des Michael Gabras},
 address = {Wien},
 publisher = {Verlag der österreichischen Akademie der Wissenschaften}
}

@article{Cotsonis.2005,
keywords = {studi},
 author = {Cotsonis, John},
 year = {2005},
 title = {The Contribution of Byzantine Lead Seals to the Study of the Cult of the Saints (Sixth-Twelfth Century)},
 pages = {383-497},
 volume = {75},
 journal = {Byzantion}
}
```

I would like that the titles that are marked by "edizioni" in the bibliografia.bib file appear with the name of the editor in the footnote, while they keep showing the name of the author in the final bibliography, as they currently do.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. In order to make your question more readble, I suggest that you add four spaces at the start of each line of code.

Comment: Welcome ... To mark that code you gave just select it and press the button `{}` (This will add the spaces suggested by @JoséCarlosSantos)